# What is the correct replacement for (PF_INET,SOCK_PACKET)

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel, obsolete

I am given a task to eliminate the

```
<app> uses obsolete (PF_INET,SOCK_PACKET)
```

warning from a userspace client. 
If this type of use is obsolete; what is the correct, similar replacement for this task?

Edit: There was misleading information here.

Comment: I really don't think that the `socket` call you are showing is responsible for the warning, I suggest you look elsewhere. perhaps in a library that you are using?

Comment: Indeed, the message comes from a library. This question is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a library function calling socket(AF_INET, SOCK_PACKET, htons(0x0806)), and not the application itself.

Comment: Then you should fix the library or get an updated version which does not. Although if it's not broken, I'd be tempted not to fix it. I don't expect the kernel to remove this feature for a while.

Comment: This feature is still present in Linux 2.6.39 and is not mentioned in the feature-removal-schedule.txt document. I guess it will probably stay for at least a few years in the mainline kernel and could persist a while longer in vendor kernels.

Comment: Thanks for the update but I have reasons to fix the library. It is developed in-house so it will not be much trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Check `man 7 packet` and `man 7 ip` for more information, but it looks like what you need is

`socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, <protocol>)`

```
"For compatibility with Linux 2.0, the obsolete socket(PF_INET,
SOCK_RAW, protocol) syntax is still supported to open a
packet(7) socket.  This is deprecated and should be replaced by
socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, protocol) instead.  The main
difference is the new sockaddr_ll address structure for generic
link layer information instead of sockaddr_pkt." - ip(7)
```

Although I don't know what additional changes might be required.